# Is it dangerous to use ThreadLocal with ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I was going through the concept of ThreadLocals on the below blog :

https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal

It says that "Do not use ThreadLocal with ExecutorService"

It illustrates below example for using ThreadLocals.

```
public class ThreadLocalWithUserContext implements Runnable {
  
    private static ThreadLocal<Context> userContext 
      = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private Integer userId;
    private UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String userName = userRepository.getUserNameForUserId(userId);
        userContext.set(new Context(userName));
        System.out.println("thread context for given userId: "
          + userId + " is: " + userContext.get());
    }
     
    // standard constructor
}
```

At the End of the post it mentions that :

> If we want to use an ExecutorService and submit a Runnable to it, using ThreadLocal will yield non-deterministic results – because we do not have a guarantee that every Runnable action for a given userId will be handled by the same thread every time it is executed.
>
> Because of that, our ThreadLocal will be shared among different userIds. That’s why we should not use a TheadLocal together with ExecutorService. It should only be used when we have full control over which thread will pick which runnable action to execute.

This explanation was a bouncer to me. I tried to do some research online for this point specifically but I could not get much help, can some expert please elaborate on the above explanation? Is it authors view or a real Threat?

Comment: As long as you init the ThreadLocal when each task begins, it's ok.

Comment: Why? If you're using `Executor Service` you already have `Runnables` or `Callables`, and you can save your data in there. No need for `ThreadLocal` whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of [that caution](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal) is that *multiple* runs of your `Runnable` may execute on different threads. An executor service can be backed by a single thread but it may just as well be backed by a pool of threads. On subsequent executions of your `Runnable`, a different thread will be accessing a different `ThreadLocal`.

So you certainly *can* use [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) within a single run of the `Runnable`. But it is not likely to be useful, as generally the purpose of a `ThreadLocal` is to hold a value for a while. In contrast, a `Runnable` should generally be short-lived.

So, no, generally it does not make sense to use a `ThreadLocal` with a thread pool.

Comment: ThreadLocalWithUserContext firstUser   = new ThreadLocalWithUserContext(1);


Let's forget about thread pool for a while and get more into the root, say if my above runnable "firstUser" is executed by two different threads, each of the thread will have its copy of ThreadLocal.So, I agree that this increases the memory footprint and makes the code vulnerable to memory leaks, but I don't see its impact on the correctness or the final output of the program, Is my understanding correct? If not, then can you please explain by example?

Comment: Probably they just want to reuse the variable, and reduce frequency of GC.

Comment: For a concrete example, will SLF4J/Log4j `MDC` work as expected for threads running in an `ExecutorService`?   For example, for threads doing real work, it's not implausible that the call stack is dozens of calls deep and some context would be helpful in the logs.  But, at the end of each `Callable` or `Runnable`, perhaps in a `finally block, the context should be cleared, e.g. `MDC.clear();`.   Unless the execution of a _single_ Runnable or Callable could change threads mid-run (e.g. if blocked for I/O), then my expectation is that MDC works (no data crossing Runnables).

Answer (score 8):

Consider a ThreadLocal to be some sort of "in memory cache" for code that is executed by the same thread. The exact same thread. It is a bad idea to share a ThreadLocal between code that is executed on different threads.

Tha javadoc clearly states:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

In other words: the *goal* of using ThreadLocals is to give "each" code running in different threads "thread specific" data.

ExecutorService  on the other hand is first of all an interface: you simply don't know if it is powered by a single thread, or (much more likely) by multiple threads.

In other words: using an ExecutorService quickly leads to *multiple different* threads running your Runnables/Tasks. And then you would be sharing your ThreadLocal amongst these multiple threads.

So, "dangerous" is maybe the wrong word. The **goal** of using ThreadLocal is to have per-thread storage, whereas an ExecutorService is about code being executed by an *unknown* number of threads. Those two things are simply not going together nicely.

The focus is different: one concept emphasises a long living thread connected to a very specific "activity". The other concept is about executing small, independent activities using an unknown number of namesless threads.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you? How can we say that a "ThreadLocal"  will be shared among threads in the pools, as each thread in the pool is capable of holding its own personal copy of ThreadLocal?

Comment: You don't have any control over which thread is running your code! That is the whole point.

Comment: Can you please explain by some example where doing this has an impact on the correctness of the program?

Comment: Turn it around: why don't you go and see to create an example that uses thread local in a meaningful way whilst being used via executor service? You consider that to be a good approach,, so why dont you see how that can work in reality?! Start there. Don't have other people do the learning for you. There is no point in asking for a counter example when you don't have a "look here it makes sense" example in the first place!

Comment: And please note: I don't say this approach is dangerous or always leading to incorrect code. I simply say that these 2 concepts enable different goals that are somehow contradicting in their purposes!

Comment: Didn't understand

Comment: In case you have a specific problem, ask a question. Adding a comment like "didnt understand" ... doesnt achieve anything.

Answer (score 4):

> ThreadLocal will yield non-deterministic results – because we do not have a guarantee that every Runnable action for a given userId will be handled by the same thread every time it is executed.

In the code example posted, the argument above is invalid because the `ThreadLocal` value is set when `run()` is called therefore any subsequent `get()` within the same block is deterministic regardless of using a `ExecutorService`.

Calling `set(new Context())` in `Runnable A` then `get()` from another `Runnable B` is not deterministic because you have no control over which `Thread` the `Runnable` is being executed.

Just assume that the object returned by `get()` could be anything unless you know when it was last set.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadLocal is used when you want to cache a variable in that thread **after** you set it. So next time when you want to access it, you can just directly get it from the ThreadLocal without initialization.

Since you set it with `threadLocal.set(obj)` and you access it via `threadLocal.get()` within a thread, so directly you have thread-safe guarantee.

But things might become ugly, if you do not clear the *cache* by `threadLocal.remove()` explicitly.

1. in a thread pool, the tasks queued up will be processed by threads one by one and the task should be independent most of the time, but the thread-scope cache threadLocal will make the following tasks depend on its previous if you forget to clear it first before handling the next task;
2. the *cached* threadLocals will not be gc-ed immediately (at some **unknown** moment - out of your control) since their keys are [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), which might cause OOM without your knowing.

A simple demo for such case where `remove()` is not explicitly invoked causing an OOM.

```
public class ThreadLocalOne {
    private static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 500;
    private static final int LIST_SIZE = 1024 * 25;

    private static ThreadLocal<List<Integer>> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                threadLocal.set(getBigList());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + threadLocal.get().size());
                // threadLocal.remove(); 
                // explicitly remove the cache, OOM shall not occur;
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private static List<Integer> getBigList() {
        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
            ret.add(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```